# Maintain this pointer in javascript using prototype

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, this

Im having an issue with using prototypes `observe` function and gaining access to this pointer. Consider the following:

```
var Demo = Class.create({
    this.someValue = "this is the value",

    initialize: function() {
        Event.observe("button1", "click", function() {
            alert(this.someValue);
        });

        Event.observe("button2", "click", this.testFunc());
    },

    testFunc: function() {
        alert(this.someValue);
    }
});
```

Clicking on both the `button1` and `button2` controls do not perform what I would like which is to have the alert display "this is the value" but instead it displays the source of the event (ie, the button). So my question is how i can achieve what i am after and have the this pointer be equal to the `Demo` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe):

> Prototype's **bind** function to the rescue. Using bind(), you can make sure your method gets the right `this`.

In your example:

```
var Demo = Class.create({

    initialize: function() {
        this.someValue = "this is the value";

        Event.observe("button1", "click", (function() {
            alert(this.someValue);
        }).bind(this));

        Event.observe("button2", "click", this.testFunc.bind(this));
    },

    testFunc: function() {
        alert(this.someValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa, this is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 2):

In the scope where `this` refers to the desired object, assign it to a variable (e.g. `self`), and then refer to the variable in the scopes in which `this` no longer refers to the desired object. Example:

```
 /**
  * @constructor
  */
 var Demo = function(){};

 /**
  * Some value
  * @type {string}
  */
 Demo.prototype.someValue = "this is the value";

 /**
  * Initializes the demo.
  */
  Demo.prototype.initialize = function() {
     var self = this;
     Event.observe("button1", "click", function() {
        alert(self.someValue);
     });
     Event.observe("button2", "click", self.testFunc());
  };

  /**
   * Prints the value
   */
  Demo.prototype.testFunc = function() {
     alert(this.someValue);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for that Michael, it really helps. However, the event for button2 does not correctly display the "someValue". The event handler for button1 works fine however. (Note, i removed the "()" from "self.testFunc" as it was an error in my original snippet. Any thoughts on how to get the button2 handling correctly?

Comment: Ok. I have managed to get it to work by using the following: "Event.observe("button2", "click", function() { self.testFunc() });". Does this seem like the a decent enough way to handle this?